# "the manual entries in section 4" in macOS manual?

Tags: macos, sockets, bind, bsd, manual

`man 2 bind` on macOS Terminal contains this comment.

> ... The rules used in address binding vary between communication domains.
> Consult **the manual entries in section 4** for detailed information.

What's the "the manual entries in section 4" and how to find it? I'm pretty sure that this is referring an entry in BSD manual, but I have no idea how to find it.

---

I tried `man 4 bind` but it says

```
No entry for bind in section 4 of the manual
```

---

[A search of the FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bind&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) manual does not show any result.

[image]

---

I tried various searches and every BSD-based manual pages say same "section 4" stuff, but no one has link to it. I see Linux manual for `bind` has more information, but it's for Linux and could be different with macOS as it is based on BSD. And I heard that `bind` can show different behaviors on different platforms. I want to get a precise manual for macOS `bind`.

The initial intention was looking for guaranteed behavior about how `bind(0)` works on macOS. I know that is likely to give binding to a free port, but I just want to check whether it is guaranteed by the OS vendor.

Comment: This link mention section 7 : https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html

Comment: @Philippe It's a Linux man page, not the macOS man page.

Comment: @Eonil there's no `bind` in the `man4` folder. My guess is that it refers to `man 4 unix`, `man 4 ip`, ... Man pages are stored inside the `/usr/share/man` folder, but I'm afraid you wont find more info there (about `bind`).

Answer (score 0):

> The rules used in address binding vary between communication domains.
> Consult the manual entries in section 4 for detailed information.

This is not referring to bind in section 4, it is referring to domains. Some examples are:

```
man 4 ip
man 4 ip6
man 4 net
```